# add radtreeview items to radtreeview root programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, radtreeview

Platform: WPF, .NET 4, Visual Studio 2010
XAML code is as below:

```
<telerik:RadTreeView x:Name="mytree"  
IsOptionElementsEnabled="True"  
IsLineEnabled="True"    
HorizontalAlignment="Left" AllowDrop="True"> 
<telerik:RadTreeViewItem Header="Root of the Tree" x:Name="myroot" AllowDrop="True">
```

I intend to add a node in the code behind like the following way:

```
RadTreeViewItem treeviewitem = new RadTreeViewItem();  
treeviewitem.Header = "some text here";  
myroot.Add(treeviewitem);
```

However it seems like there is no Add method in the radtreeviewitem class. Intellisense does not give that option when I try to do it. How should I proceed?

Comment: How about "myRoot.Items.Add(treeviewitem)"?

Comment: No problem.  =)  I posted the answer for this question below.  Please just mark it as correct.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "myRoot.Items.Add(treeviewitem)" instead.